# what is https://myds.com:port in Synology web api?

Tags: web, apple-watch, synology

I want to develop a apple watch app to control  my Synology nas remotely。First at all, I need to login my  Synology.
I read the document

https://global.synologydownload.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Os/DSM/All/enu/DSM_Login_Web_API_Guide_enu.pdf

The documentation mentions that I need to use NAS  address is https://myds.com:port,
how can I get it ? or use another alternative（I have quickconnect username, password and quickconnect id)